# Can you lease a secondary residential apartment for a job in NYC, and declare it as expense in tax return?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, limited-liability-company, rent, real-estate-leasing

Currently I commute over 2 hours to work in NYC.  Thus I would like to rent a apartment close to where I work.

Is there a way to have your rental payment declared as expense in your tax return?

One possible way I see doing it would be lease the apartment through a LLC, and the apartment could be considered as a necessity for a business activity.

Any ideas?

Comment: Expenses that arise because you choose to live far away from your job are not deductible. If you hide those expenses by going through various corporate entities that you control the IRS might not notice, but it's still tax fraud.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it...

Generally housing can't be considered a business expense unless taken at your employer's explicit direction, for the good of the business rather than the employee. Temporary assignment far enough from you home office that commuting or occasional hotel nights are impractical,  maybe.

In other words, if they wouldn't be (at least theoretically) willing to let you put it on an expense account, you probably can't claim it here.